# Is it possible to clear the x using the Lambert function?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w

$ y = \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{ln(x)}{2} $

Solving, I get to:

$ e^{4y} = \frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2} $

But I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\ln(x)}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{2\ln(x)}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=\frac{x^2-2\ln(x)}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$4y=x^2-2\ln(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\exp[4y]=\exp\left[x^2-2\ln(x)\right]\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\exp[4y]=\frac{\exp\left[x^2\right]}{x^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Sustitute $x^2=u$

---

$$\exp[4y]=\frac{\exp\left[u\right]}{u}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$u=-\text{W}_n\left[-\frac{1}{e^{4y}}\right]\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2=-\text{W}_n\left[-\frac{1}{e^{4y}}\right]\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Notice:

- $$\sqrt{\text{W}_n\left[-\frac{1}{e^{4y}}\right]}\ne0$$
- $$n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
- $\text{W}_k(z)$ is the analytic continuation of the product log function

  ---

$$x=\pm\sqrt{-\text{W}_n\left[-\frac{1}{e^{4y}}\right]}$$

Comment: I have a doubt: how to demonstrate $ u = -Wn(-z^{-1}) <==> z = u^{-1} e^{u} $ from $ u = Wn(z) <==> z = ue^{u} $

Comment: @RonaldBecerra Do you know the definition of the product log function?